# Buchberger's algorithm for finding groebner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, groebner-basis

Consider running Buchberger's algorithm on the polynomials $f=x_3-x_1^5,$ $g=x_2-x_1^3$ with lexicographic order and $x_1>x_2>x_3$. 
We first compute the $S$-polynomial. We have $LT(f)=-x_1^5,\ LT(g)=-x_1^3$. So $$S(f,g)=\frac{x_1^5}{-x_1^5}(x_3-x_1^5)-\frac{x_1^5}{-x_1^3}(x_2-x_1^3)=x_1^2x_2-x_3.$$

Now, this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437898/buchbergers-algorithm) says the remainder when divide $S(f,g)$ with $\{f,g\}$ is $S(f,g)$. So, we add $S(f,g)$ to the current Groebner basis.

I didn't understand this part. The polynomial $x_1^2x_2-x_3$ can be expressed as $-f+x_1^2g$. So, the remainder when we divide $S(f,g)$ with $\{f,g\}$ is 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

[Reduction (multivariable division)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis#Reduction) and ideal membership are generally different concepts. "$S(f,g)$ is not reduced to $0$ by $\{f,g\}$" does not necessarily mean $S(f,g)\not\in\langle f,g\rangle$. Reduction and ideal membership are matched when we use Groebner basis (that's one of the reasons why we want to compute Groebner basis). Anyway, let's follow the algorithm **as it is defined**.

Let me explain the difference in another way. Can you say that $1$ is divisible by $\{2,3\}$ just because $1$ can be expressed as $-2 + 3$?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Can you please include the reduction algorithm we are supposed to use? Because from your answer, even if $S(f,g) = p_1 f + p_2 g$, we don't accept that $S(f,g)$ is reduced to 0. So, I want to know what are the acceptable values of $p_1$ and $p_2$.

Comment: @satya  After reading the comment, I edited the answer to add a link. Did you read the linked article? If the divisor is a set, the reduction (division algorithm) we are supposed to use does not consider all the elements at once, but consider dividing one by one by each element.